# Directly accessing application.cfc produces untrapped ColdFusion error

Tags: coldfusion, error-handling, application.cfc

I'm developing a new ColdFusion 9 application using application.cfc, and just for kicks I wanted to see what happens if I navigate directly to application.cfc, like this:

http://www.mysite.com/application.cfc

I was somewhat surprised to see an untrapped error, the meat of which is:

"Invalid request of Application.cfm, Application.cfc, or OnRequestEnd.cfm file"

After some digging around, it appears that there's no real way to handle this within the application itself--or at least no way that I've found thus far.

Are there any decent solutions for this problem out there?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you don't want to use the site-wide error handler, you could simply make the Application.cfc not web browseable, then let your 404-handler deal with it.

Comment: potentially ignorant question:  how does one do this in IIS?

Comment: Good question.  I would have thought just right-clicking > properties > switch off the READ setting.  But that doesn't work for me: IIS still passes it to CF (which I believe it should not).  I am no expert in IIS though.  Fortunately for you, there is Google... ;-)

Comment: Google?  What is this Google of which you speak?  (-;  I searched around a bit and didn't (yet) find an answer.  I'll keep digging and post findings back here.

Comment: Heh.  Yeah, sorry, I was gonna ask one of our sysadmins what the story is, but they're both off today.  When i find out, I'll come back to ya.

Comment: OK, spoke to our sysadmin.  He was equally surprised that IIS still passes requests for CF files to CF even if the file is marked as "not readable" in IIS.  He reckons the easiest way of working around this is to create a rewrite to redirect requests for Application.cfc to your 404 handler.

Comment: Yup. [space filler because just "yup" ain't long enough apparently]

Comment: Thanks, Adam.  And...ick.  I hate that, too.  (-;  I want all of this to be self contained within the CF application.  Anyway, it's good to know about URL rewrite stuff for IIS, but I think I probably need to vote for the CF-based solution, above.

Comment: For what it's worth, I circled back to this today, and after nosing around in IIS7, I found an answer.  IIS7 has a "Request Filtering" option.  Click on that, and you can either "Allow URL..." or "Deny Sequence...".  I selected "Deny Sequence...", then typed "application.cfc" in the field IIS presented, and voila!  Requests to application.cfc were suddenly picked up by my missing page handler.  This is way better, in my opinion, than the CF site-wide error handler.  No answer for IIS6, but that's okay, I think.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is to use the global error handler via ColdFusion Administrator:

[image]

Here, you'll enter in the value of a cf template that you build, and trap the necessary errors that come in as a result of direct access to Application.cfc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply...but I hate this solution.  (-;  If you have more than one CF application running on a server (as I do), then this isn't so great.  Is this really the only option?

Comment: I don't think there is another solution as Application.cfc or Application.cfm are files which call first with every request.

Comment: I'm declaring this to be the answer, even though I hate it.  It feels like a bug in Cold Fusion, and here's hoping that it gets "fixed" in future releases.